# Jekyll does not render theme layout when using index.html in Github Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I'm trying to learn how to use Github pages, so I've created my first page and added the [Jekyll cayman](https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman) theme to it.

Before adding the theme I could just use an index.html file to render my main page. However, now that I have added the cayman theme, the index.html file is not read anymore and only the index.md file is read.

Resulting github page:
https://scinana.github.io/hellopages/

Code:
https://github.com/scinana/hellopages

Why am I forced to add an index.md file?

What if I want to keep using html files directly instead of an md file? Can I use html files while using a Jekyll theme?

Comment: Thanks for editing this question Christian,  but I wonder if the title is accurate now? My question was trying to understand why only the md files are rendered and not the direct HMTL ones when using a jekyll theme, does this make sense?

Comment: The problem was that only the html was rendered, so I guess it's accurate now.

Comment: Ok thank you! It's not entirely clear to me but I trust what you say :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an html file. Just add a front matter and insert the default layout.

Here's an example:

```
---
layout: default
---
  
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is the title of the webpage!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is an example paragraph. Anything in the <strong>body</strong> tag will appear on the page, just like this <strong>p</strong> tag and its contents.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

From https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/04-layouts/:

> Layouts are templates that can be used by any page in your site and wrap around page content. They are stored in a directory called _layouts.

From https://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/:

> **index.html or index.md and other HTML, Markdown files**
> Provided that the file has a front matter section, it will be transformed by Jekyll. The same will happen for any `.html`, `.markdown`, `.md`, or `.textile` file in your site’s root directory or directories not listed above.

Comment: Thank you so much for this Christian! Your answer helps a lot!